# Xamarin not showing code

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin

When I open some previously saved solutions in Xamarin, that were made in Xamarin, the code doesn't show up, but if i run it, it still works. So the code is there just not showing up, does anyone know if this is a setting i'm missing, or have i done something wrong?

I also found that if the program runs and throws an error the code will appear and everything will be back to normal.

Comment: Are you using Xamarin Studio?  Is the code editor just hidden?  If you open Solution Pad and double-click on a source file does it open?

Comment: Yeah i think thats it was only single clicking on it, thanks Jason.